# The value of a symbol determined by GCC during compiling/linking

Tags: c, gcc, hyperlink, elf

Why in below code "if (sqrt)" condition is alway true? When compiling, gcc warns like this,

```
weak.c: In function âfâ:
weak.c:6: warning: the address of âsqrtâ, will always evaluate as âtrueâ
```

Source code，

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern double sqrt(double x); /* DECLARATION VERSION 1 */
/* extern double sqrt(double x) __attribute__ ((weak)); */ /* DECLARATION VERSION 2 */

void f() {
        if (sqrt) {
                printf("sqrt of 10 %f \n", sqrt(10.0));
        }
        else {
                printf("sqrt not found \n");
        }
}

int main (int arg, char **argv)
{
        f();
        return 0;
}
```

If I comment out line-"DECLARATION VERSION 1" and uncomment line-"DECLARATION VERSION 2", I have a binary with below behavior.

- When the binary is linked with -lm, the "if (sqrt)" is true.
- When not, the condition is false. I know/think for a weak symbol, here is the "sqrt" function, it's initialized with 0 when linking. Therefore, when the "sqrt" symbol can't find its definition in other place(library), the "if (sqrt)" condition is false.

However, when I use "DECLARATION VERSION 1", why "sqrt" is always no-zero? In "DECLARATION VERSION 1", the "sqrt" is not a weak symbol, of course nor strong symbol. Actually, you can't find the "sqrt" symbol, when you use "nm" command. What's more, when I try to print out the address of "sqrt", I get a compilation error.

Does someone know the reason why "sqrt" is no-zero?

Thanks in advance!

As I can't find a proper title to describe my question, please suggest a better one if any.

**I think I find the reason:**

gcc has a builtin sqrt() function for optimization purposes. If possible, gcc will replace calling of sqrt() in libm with its builtin sqrt(), http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html. When compiling, if builtin functions not turned off and libm(-lm) not given, gcc will use its builtin version of sqrt(), which always has no-zero address. **when I turn off builtin, I get a compiling error**,

```
$ gcc -fno-builtin weak.c
weak.c: In function âfâ:
weak.c:9: warning: the address of âsqrtâ, will always evaluate as âtrueâ
/tmp/cc84fwK9.o: In function `f':
weak.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `sqrt'
weak.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3):

In both cases `sqrt()` is a function. For decl ver 1, In the if statement:

```
if (sqrt)
```

`sqrt` resolves to the *address* of that function, which is known at compile time (and cannot be zero anyway). Because in C, anything non-zero is true, the if statement's condition, the address of the function, always evaluates to true :)

When you use `__attribute__ ((weak))`, the compiler allows you to "check" if a function exists. If it does not, the symbol is still created, but is set to NULL. So when you've made it a "weak"ly linked function the symbol `sqrt` may be `null`(false).

[***From wikipedia***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol)...

> In computing, a weak symbol is a symbol definition in an object file
>   or dynamic library that may be overridden by other symbol definitions.
>   Its value will be zero if no definition is found by the loader.

So to conclude, in decl version 1, the linker must find the function `sqrt` at compile time and will bind the function's address to that symbol. Therefore the symbol cannot be null.

In decl version 2, the linker doesn't need to find `sqrt`. If it does, `sqrt` will resolve to the function address, but if it does not find the function, it will set that symbol to `null`. I.e., weak symbols permit you to define symbols that don’t need to be resolved at link time...

Also from [***GNU Compiler Function Attributes***](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

> The weak attribute causes the declaration to be emitted as a weak
>   symbol rather than a global. This is primarily useful in defining
>   library functions which can be overridden in user code, though it can
>   also be used with non-function declarations. Weak symbols are
>   supported for ELF targets, and also for a.out targets when using the
>   GNU assembler and linker.

Not only does this allow you to check if the function exists, but it allows you, as mentioned above, to override a function. See [***Understand Weak Symbols by Examples***](http://winfred-lu.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/understand-weak-symbols-by-examples.html) for a neat little example and some useful references (especially good - [***GCC Weak Symbols***](http://www.embedded-bits.co.uk/2008/gcc-weak-symbols/) - gives example of weak function symbol being overridden by a strong function symbol).

Comment: Hi, Jimbo, you said "sqrt resolves to the address of that function, which is known at compile time (and cannot be zero anyway)". However, I compile the code without passing "-lm" option so that gcc will not find the address/definition of the sqrt function. Then how its address is known at compile time?

Comment: I think because `sqrt` is part of the standard library and is linked to by default. What does `m` do? I suspect the std lib is linked against by default... not 100% sure. But for certain all symbols are resolved at compile (well link) time :) I think you need to use linker option `-nostdlib` to stop linking against the standard library. That is why, I suspect, you can still resolve the `sqrt` symbol... (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

Comment: I'm not suggesting you don't link against the standard library btw... it's just an example explanation as to why the symbol still exists for you :)

Comment: Okay, so that's how the symbol is known at compile time. I didn't know about the built ins, so thanks for posting what you found :)